# Android ndk static zlib

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm attempting to use the gradle-experimental to build a native library.  If I link the library shared it builds fine.  However if I use static linking it fails trying to find `uncompress` in zlib.

native dependency:

```
    ndk {
        moduleName "native"

        ldLibs.add("log")
        ldLibs.add("z")

        stl "gnustl_static"
    }
```

library:

```
    sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    project ":native" linkage "static"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ndk {
        moduleName "processor"
        stl "gnustl_shared"
    }
```

Dropping the `linkage "static"` so it creates a shared library works fine.  Is there a reason ndk would fail to use the static zlib (which does exist in the platform libs)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set **ldFlags** manually to be sure it takes static library for correct abi (if you build for more then one). I'd also look at gcc/clang output to see what libraries and where it takes to compile a project.

Comment: ldFlags was broken until recently I believe.  I'll try that.  Would gcc normally look for the static library, ie: is this likely a bug in gradle-experimental?

Comment: I have only built projects with other 3rd party static libraries, and everything I've done with ldFlags worked normally. So you should try, I think.